# What does "maligned sacred" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I know what "maligned" and "sacred" mean in separate but "maligned sacred" sounds an unusual collocation to me. I wonder what it means in the following context.

"The concentration camp is a structure that places some subjects outside the law, as the maligned sacred, while also subjecting them brutally to the law's force."

Comment: It echoes 'the living dead'.

Comment: I wonder whether the author was thinking of the occupants of the camp as being sacrifices to the god of the people who set up the camp. In the most obvious case that the Jews were sacrificed to the ideal of 'racial purity'. In that sense they could be analagous to sacrificial animals ritually dedicated to sacrifice but held in pens within a temple.